# limiting union result in oracle

Tags: oracle, union

I need to limit the result of a union query, using oracle :

```
Select 
...
Union
Select
...
```

I need to limit it to top 500 results, but without using "with".

Any ideeas ?
Thank you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This query will select 500 records from your union query:

```
select *
  from ( select
            ...
          union
         select
            ...
       )
 where rownum <= 500
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
SELECT top 500 myResult.* FROM (
Select  
... 
Union 
Select ) AS myResult
```

Comment: He asked for a query "using oracle" and "top 500" is not Oracle syntax.